# Is this an objective-c block?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I came across some code in an opensource library called SIAlertView and I am not sure what it is doing?  Specifically the two lines below?  What is SIAleartViewHandler as it is not a class in the SIAlertView library?

```
typedef void(^SIAlertViewHandler)(SIAlertView *alertView);
@property (nonatomic, copy) SIAlertViewHandler willShowHandler;
```

SIAlertView.h

```
typedef void(^SIAlertViewHandler)(SIAlertView *alertView);
@property (nonatomic, copy) SIAlertViewHandler willShowHandler;
@property (nonatomic, copy) SIAlertViewHandler didShowHandler;
@property (nonatomic, copy) SIAlertViewHandler willDismissHandler;
@property (nonatomic, copy) SIAlertViewHandler didDismissHandler;
```

SIAlertView.m

```
[self transitionInCompletion:^{
    if (self.didShowHandler) {
        self.didShowHandler(self);
    }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SIAlertViewDidShowNotification object:self userInfo:nil];

    [SIAlertView setAnimating:NO];

    NSInteger index = [[SIAlertView sharedQueue] indexOfObject:self];
    if (index < [SIAlertView sharedQueue].count - 1) {
        [self dismissAnimated:YES cleanup:NO]; // dismiss to show next alert view
    }
}];

#pragma mark - SIAlertItem

@interface SIAlertItem : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, assign) SIAlertViewButtonType type;
@property (nonatomic, copy) SIAlertViewHandler action;

@end

@implementation SIAlertItem

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line (`typedef void(^SIAlertViewHandler)(SIAlertView *alertView);`) defines a type of block, called `SIAlertViewHandler`.

The second line (`@property (nonatomic, copy) SIAlertViewHandler willShowHandler;`) defines a property which is going to store an instance of that block type.

Comment: What about the @interface SIAlertItem : NSObject being defined inside another classes .m file?

Comment: It's a class, just like any other, but only accessible from inside this file (because there is no public definition of its existence).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a block.

The first line is creating a new type to add a bit of sanity to using said block  (instead of having to repeat `void(^)(SIAlertView *alertView)` everywhere, you can just use `SIAlertViewHandler`.

`SIAlertView.m` is checking to see if the `showHandler` is set and, if so, calling the block.